# Kue UI (Express) parallel to Hapi.JS API-Server

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js, kue

I want to use the UI from Kue (https://github.com/Automattic/kue) parallel to my Hapi.js Application.

The Kui UI is build with Express.

Hapi and Express are listening on port 80 on my heroku dyno.

How can I do that? Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post is lacking a bit of details but I think I understand what you want.  I will assume that both services run on the same IP@ so you obviously can't have them both on port 80.

I think a possible solution is to start `kue` on another port (say 4080) and have hapi.js proxy the `kue` routes to the `kue` server.

The relevant document section is [here](http://hapijs.com/api/7.5.2#route-options)  (look for the `proxy` option).  There is a sample [here](http://tech.opentable.co.uk/blog/2014/11/28/proxying-with-hapi/).

Hope I got your question right.